# Preguntas sobre programacion en Android

Tags: android

Estoy interesado en el desarrollo de software para *Android*, pero me siento un poco perdido, por lo que tengo un par de dudas:

- ¿Por donde se debería empezar?
- ¿Que lenguajes hay para Android? (Aparte de Java)
- ¿Cual lenguaje es el mejor para trabajar en este SO?
- ¿Que IDE se debería usar?

**PD:** *Agradecería si alguien conoce algun buen libro para aprender sobre programación en Android*

Comment: Malthael, [tu pregunta se basa en opiniones](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), es posible que sea cerrada. Por ejemplo, para tu primera pregunta, yo te remitiría a [Primeros pasos en Developer Android](https://developer.android.com/training/index.html)...

Comment: Gracias Mauricio, revisare eso

Comment: Empieza con descargarte el Android Studio, aprende un poco de Java basico, hazte con un terminal android y googlea